# How to Show Switch widget exactly in the center of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

I am trying to add switch widget in my layout.
Problem i am encountering is widget appears on the right side living a space for its text(but i don't want any text. it appears like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dr54.png)

but what i want is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjLQw.png)

I had tried a few ways like using nested layouts( it works well for small screen but when i try it on tabs then due to large screen it acquire more space and ultimately it shifts slightly toward right leaving space for text even though i did't entered any text).

the xml code i am currently using

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="11">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"></LinearLayout>

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sosswitch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"></LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

I am using the above code to bring the switch in middle but it still create problem in large screens.

Comment: XML Code pls. What have you tried?

Comment: posted...... you can check.... thanks

Comment: Um, you didn't need to put the whole xml. Just one instance of the required element with its parents would have been enough.

Comment: should i remove the remaining. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Yes. Though its fine. I'll edit the code.

Comment: is it fine now....

Comment: Yup. Thats fine. So found your problem. The enforced weight is increasing the layout width for the `Switch`

Comment: Can you use `RelativeLayout` or is your constraint such that you need to work only with `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: i can use that also.... i don't have any restrictions...  you have my full xml code... if you can spare time then can you edit and send me your proposed answer

Comment: Um, I am sorry, but don't have lot of time. Have given the reason and how to solve it. You'll have to implement that in your code buddy. It should be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no constraint to use just `LinearLayout`, using `RelativeLayout` will solve your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/sosswitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

The problem was due to the extension of width of the `Switch` element due to the use of `weight` system in Linear Layout. To align the `Switch` in center here, `layout_centerInParent` is used.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Comment: can you suggest where i can study android like any book or somewhere else in detail......      here you used (layout_centerInParent).  which i never used or hear of...

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) by Google on Android is a very good reference point.  As for books, I haven't gone through any of them (your preferences) . I would suggest NewBoston Android tutorials, and general Google and SO, along with **building your own application**.